# GLib for embedded Linux?

Tags: embedded, glib

I am wondering~

How large is GLib? Can it be used directly on embedded system? Is it usually too large for embedded system?

Is there a embedded system version of GLib?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

"Embedded" barely means anything. The systems range from tiny (few registers of volatile memory, read-only code memory) to nearly as big as computers have ever been on this planet.

Glib isn't huge as desktop libraries go, but it's not a tiny microcontroller library either. There's obviously a vague line somewhere in that range below which it just won't fit, but without knowing the system there's no way to tell.

Based on a comment it seems your environment ranks "ginormous" in the embedded scale, so glib will probably fit if the system underneath makes porting it worthwhile. If you have a GPOS (like Linux or BSD), there might already be a port.

Answer (score 1):

If you can fit GLibC then you can fit GLib.

Comment: glibc has its embedded version called uclibc.
so I am asking if Glib has a similar embedded version

Answer (score 1):

GLIB can be used for embedded systems and is quite small.  However, newer
versions of GLIB require a lot more libraries to build.  If what you need
is a subset like async queues, threads, queues, lists, etc., you might
consider getting the code and building GLIB 1.2.x instead of the latest.

I have been considering building a subset of GLIB for embedded work that
removes some of the newer features.

Answer (score 0):

How large storage space do you have on your embedded device? There is no problem compiling Glib for an embedded device, given that you have enough storage on your device. Since we don't know anything about your device, it's kind of hard to say though.

Comment: our device has 128M DRAM and 32M flash

Comment: My guess is that it won't be a big problem adding glib. A rough calculation shows that our glib uses less than 2MB. This is compiled for an armv7 cortex9a chip.

Comment: Ok, upticking your comment for general usefulness. The system I have has 120kb flash and 20kb RAM. I can stop looking, GLib ain't gonna fit...